# Visual Studio 2008: Don't deploy SQL Server Compact 3.5 when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, sql-server-ce

I'm using VS2008 to create a Compact Framework application for a Windows CE 5.0 device (Datalogic Kyman). I'm using SQL Server Compact 3.5 in my application. However, I'm debugging on a Kyman that still has Windows CE 4.2 installed (attached via USB using Mobile Device Center). My problem:

VS2008 does not recognize that SQL Server Compact is already installed on the device and asks me to install SQL Server Compact **every time** I'm running my application from the IDE. The installer shows me a warning about the SQL Server Compact CAB file not being suitable for this device, but installation works without errors, also the application works without errors.

I've unchecked the box "Always deploy latest .NET version" (don't know what it's called in English exactly, using German VS2008), but that doesn't help.

How can I tell Visual Studio **not** to install the SQL Server before launching my application every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Server Compact 3.5 Support WindowsCE 4.2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=38ed2670-a70a-43b3-87f3-7ab67b56cbf2&displaylang=en)

1- Check if target Device is Windows CE?

2- Try to install SQL Server Compact 3.5 on the device by using the cab file specified to windows CE 4.2.

you will find the cap file in the following path:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce400\armv4\sqlce.dev.ENU.ppc.wce4.armv4.CAB

Comment: Did not work for me - I installed the CAB files, but VS 2008 still wants to install the SQL Server Compact. I've also installed the WCE 5 CAB files manually, same result.

Comment: Project done - problem doesn't bug me until I need to develop for that customer again. I'll accept your answer anyways.